# Issues with interactions and formatting of ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I was compelled by another question to try some things in ggplotly. I used the code from that question. I am interested in the output , more than the content. I see issues with output formatting and items not working.

I have "simple" plot in ggplot and would like to wrap it with ggplotly. I specify a bar color using fill= and when I do the bar inacticivity goes away.

```
library(ggplot2)

library(plotly)
cnt <-c(2,1)
date <- c("2016-01-05 13:53:43","2016-01-15 09:33:40")
xx.df <- data.frame(date,cnt)
xx.df$datep <- as.Date(xx.df$date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
xx.df$datea <- as.character(xx.df$date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
xx.df$status <- as.factor(c("Success","Fail"))

pa <- ggplot(xx.df,aes(x=datea,y=cnt,fill=status))
pa <- pa+geom_bar(stat="identity")
print(ggplotly(pa))
```

1) I can't click to remove a series using the legend, both bars go away.
2) Mouse hover is not present.

[image: plotly image with fill= used]

When I remove fill= I get a grey plot without a legend. But the mouse hover works..

```
pag <- ggplot(xx.df,aes(x=datea,y=cnt))

pag <- pag+geom_bar(stat="identity")

print(ggplotly(pag))
```

[image: plotly image without fill=]

Is there an issue with how I used the fill=? I am using plotly 4.5.6,ggplot2 2.2.1

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

There seems to an issue with ggplotly and even plotly needing two results for each group. When only 1 element for the group. In this case "Fail". The mouse hover doesn't work on Fail.

```
library(ggplot2)

library(plotly)
cnt <-c(2,1,3)
date <- c("2016-01-05 13:53:43","2016-01-15 09:33:40","2016-01-18 13:53:43")
xx.df <- data.frame(date,cnt)
xx.df$datep <- as.Date(xx.df$date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
xx.df$datea <- as.character(xx.df$date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
xx.df$status <- as.factor(c("Success","Fail","Success"))

pa <- ggplot(xx.df,aes(x=datea,y=cnt,fill=status))
pa <- pa+geom_bar(stat="identity")
print(ggplotly(pa))
```

[image: The result where mouse hover works only for the Success bars]

Add at least 2 for each group and it all works.. All bars have mouse hover..
    library(ggplot2)

```
library(plotly)
cnt <-c(2,1,3,4)
date <- c("2016-01-05 13:53:43","2016-01-15 09:33:40","2016-01-18    13:53:43","2016-01-25 13:53:43")
xx.df <- data.frame(date,cnt)
xx.df$datep <- as.Date(xx.df$date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
xx.df$datea <- as.character(xx.df$date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
xx.df$status <- as.factor(c("Success","Fail","Success","Fail"))

pa <- ggplot(xx.df,aes(x=datea,y=cnt,fill=status))
pa <- pa+geom_bar(stat="identity")
print(ggplotly(pa))
```

[image: Mouse hover and clicking on legend works for all]